# Handlebars conditionals

Tags: if-statement, handlebars.js

I was surprised when I read Handlebars won't let you put a conditional with little logic like (If something === 1...) , so I'm really stuck on how to make this a Handlebar template.

```
 if {{price_type}} == 1
    Example
 else if {{price_type}} == 2
   {{min_price}}
 else
    No price
```

How is this dealt with in Handlebars? Thanks guys

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by writing your own template helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('conditionalHelper', function(lValue, rValue, options) {
    if (lValue == rValue) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

This helper will accept two values 'lValue' and 'rValue' and return true or false depending on whether these values are equal or not. We can use this helper in the example given above as follows-

```
{{#conditionalHelper price_type 1}}
    Example
{{else}}
    {{#conditionalHelper price_type 2}}
        {{min_price}}
    {{else}}
        No price
    {{/conditionalHelper}}
{{/conditionalHelper}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The handlebars if-helper only works for boolean values. So when you want to perform conditional operations on them you need to create your own helper.

```
{{#ifPriceType price_type min_type}}{{/ifPriceType}}


Handlebars.registerHelper("ifPriceType",function(price_type,min_type){
if(price_type==1){ return "Example";}
else if(price_type==2){ return min_type;}
else return "No price";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even achieve in template itself like below:

```
 if {{price_type}} == 1
    Example
 else 
          if {{price_type}} == 2
          {{min_price}}

          else
          No price
```